# grunt-html2js and injecting the 'templates-xxx' module (a dash in the module name)

Tags: angularjs

With `grunt-html2js` I'm getting a `views.js` which contains:

```
 angular.module('templates-dist', ['../views/attachment-modal.html', ...

 ...

 angular.module("../views/attachment-modal.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) { ...

 (etc. all the views)
```

I've added this module to my `app.js`, like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'templates-dist', // <--- there it is.
'ui.select']);
```

I want to add this module also to my `routes.js`, using array notation:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(['$routeProvider', 'templates-dist', function($routeProvider, X) { ... }
```

But, as you can see, I don't know how to do that, because of the "`-`" sign

**Question**: In the previous piece of code, what should I put in the X?
I think that putting `templates-dist` without quotes will be evaluated in javascript as a substraction

Also, bonus question: after injecting the `templates-dist` module, the loading of the views will automatically be from `templateCache` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to add this to the config phase of your myApp module.  There is no provider associated with templates-dist and it will throw an error because of that.  You can inject it as a dependencies to a module like you did above

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'templates-dist', // <--- there it is.
    'ui.select']);
```

but you cannot do anything with it and therefore shouldn't include it in the config phase of your application.

In regards to your `$templateCache` cache question.  I see in your example above you have

```
 angular.module('templates-dist', ['../views/attachment-modal.html', ...
```

Usually with Grunt html2js it will create a module with dependencies of your templates as modules, i.e. `attachement-modal.html` and the module would look something like this:

```
angular.module("attachement-modal.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("step.html", "YOUR HTML HERE");
}]);
```

So yes that is now stored and served from `$templateCache`

Comment: Regarding my first question: Ah! perfect!. Regarding my second question: yes, indeed I have all my views compiled to modules like that. How I get sure I'm getting my views from templateCache? because I still see the ajax call using the chrome network inspector. I'm not sure if they are being served from the (local) server or not.

Comment: Well I've uploaded so I don't have to check local and the routeProvider is bringing everything from the server and not from the templateCache :-/

Comment: Ok it wasn't working because the name of the generated modules didn't match the key passed to `templateUrl`, that is: `templateUrl: 'this-key-didnt-match-the-name-of-the-module'`